# Auto update E4 application, unable to get current running IProfile

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have requirement to develop E4 application which updates automatically when updates found, on launch of application. Currently I have exported feature in local folder. Have multiple version of feature. So application should check for latest version of feature and if available it should install on launch and restart.

I have gone through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfNIt_b5mt4 and I wont see the code in repo.
I am not able to get below bundles
getBundle("org.eclipse.equinox.p2.exomplorysetup").start(Bundle.START_TRANSIENT);
getBundle("org.eclipse.equinox.p2.simpleconfigurator.manipulator").start(Bundle.START_TRANSIENT);

Also I have gone through https://github.com/modular-mind/updatemanager.

I have used com.modumind.updatemanager.example.ui code but Profiles are not getting created and I see null.

```
private ProvisioningJob getInstallJob(ProvisioningSession provisioningSession) {
        IStatus loadStatus = loadP2Repository(provisioningSession.getProvisioningAgent());
        if (loadStatus != Status.OK_STATUS) {
            dumpStatus(loadStatus);
            return null;
        }

        IProfile profile = profileRegistry.getProfile(IProfileRegistry.SELF);
        if (profile == null) {
            this.log(
                    "No profile found for this installation, ending auto update process. Profiles are not available when running in Eclipse.");
            return null;
        }}
```

Pls help, if there are any sample applications pls share.

Comment: You say "e4" but a pure e4 RCP doesn't include any of the p2 code - so is this really e4 or just a compatability mode RCP (using the org.eclipse.ui plugins and the p2 code)? Your question is expecting us to watch a video and look at a github project - that isn't going to happen.

Comment: Greg, The request is not to watch video and look at github project. I searched in google for Auto update and got sample project. I am unable to get current running profile, hence I am unable to proceed further. If there is any simple and sample rcp java application which auto updates pls share it would be helpful...or reference is also is fine.

Comment: What does _"I have gone through"_ mean? Do you get the same issue running the unmodified mentioned GitHub repository? Eclipse itself has built-in auto update.

Comment: "I have gone through" means updatemanager was perfect example which I got from github. I imported to eclipse and ran the product. I see null while getting IProfile. Hence need help. Sharing reference to sample project which does auto update would also be helpful.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I guess this is because you run it as Eclipse application from within Eclipse rather than as a product that has been built. Are you aware that you could configure the defaults of the preferences _Install/Update > Automatic Updates_ via `plugin_customization.ini`? https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application

Comment: Thanks all for your reply, I found a way and issue resolved..